# Use twist to improve stall characteristics in ideal distribution of lift coefficient

Tags: stall, glider, sailplane, vortex-generators

Is practical use twist (geometric or multiple airfoils to improve stall characteristics) when it has lift coefficient distribution ideal or near due to wing plataform?

I am analyzing a "Schuemann" wing, and I am in the dilemma of whether to use a twist (multiple airfoils or geometrical) to improve stall and look for compromise or investigate other forms directly (vortex generator, e.g.).

[image: Is to a Sailplane project]

Comment: What do you mean with improve stall characteristics? An higher max AoA? A milder stall? An earlier stall warming?

Comment: Stall warning. I chose the airfoil with higher max AOA and docile stall. Thanks

Comment: @andy  What type of ship is this...a sailplane?? powered aircraft?  Is this full scale, or RC?